# REST Web Service for Tomcat

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey

I am trying to implement a RESTful Web Service using Tomcat 8 and java 1.7.
I tried Jersey JAX-RS API, with guidance of tutorials and other questions here, but nothing works. The best I get is a 404-HTTP status code or an empty page.

Deploying on Tomcat in general works, just not as an REST Service.

It would be nice if someone could point out an working tutorial with a similar setup. (The setup is not changeable)

Any way to implement the rest service is fine as long as it works with the setup.

Comment: Why is the setup not changeable?

Comment: It's a uni-project and they provide the server, which uses this setup. Upgrade to Java 1.8 is probably possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to set it up properly, although it's not the best and not meant to be done this way. (Importing the example jersey-project and modify it)

1. Use Maven Archetype:
   mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes  -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.6 -DgroupId=com.example -Dpackage=com.example -Dversion=1.0 -DinteractiveMode=false -DartifactId=jersey-basic-2.6
2. Copy dependencies (You have to change directories into the one with the POM.xml):
   mvn dependency:copy-dependencies

now the project is working and you can modify it however you want. To deploy it you have to create the WAR-File using Maven package (mvn package).

For development I found Intellij a lot easier to use in this use-case,
as the automatic deployment is a lot easier to setup than in eclipse.